# How to choose more important value from one column for value in corresponding column in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

- VAL1 - character
- ID - numeric
- VAL2 - character (with only 3 options: P, C, S)

| VAL1 | ID | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 123 | P |
| P1 | 123 | P |
| P1 | 123 | S |
| S2 | 44 | C |
| S2 | 44 | S |
| GG | 44 | P |
| P1 | 58 | S |
| P1 | 58 | S |

And I need to make something like this:

- If some "ID" has at least once P or C in "VAL2" then stay this "ID" with P or C for the corresponding value from column "VAL1" and of course each "ID" has to be only one time in output.
- else if some "ID" do not has P or C in "VAL2" then take what it has, so S

So as a result I need something like below:

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | P1 | P |
| 44 | S2 | C |
| 44 | GG | P |
| 58 | P1 | S |

How can I do that in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide? (Of course code could be also in normal SAS not PROC SQL) :).

Comment: ID = 58 does not have P or S in VAL2?

Comment: Yes, because if some ID do not have P or C in VAL2 then stay with value S -> there is only 3 options in VAL2: P, C or S -> P and C are more important than S

Comment: I can also add that ID can not have P and C for the same VAL1 it could be either P or C (of of course S if do not has P or C) :)

Comment: PeterClemmensen, do you have some idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could definitely be done more elegantly. But this should work just fine.

```
data have;
    input VAL1 $2. ID VAL2 $1.;
    datalines;
P1 123 P
P1 123 P
P1 123 S
S2 44 C
S2 44 S
GG 44 P
P1 58 S
P1 58 S
;
run;

proc sort data=have out=sorted nodupkey;
by ID descending VAL2;
run;

data want;
    set sorted;
    by ID;
    if VAL2 in ('P' 'C') then output;
    else if last.ID then output;
run;
```